# USB 2.0 not working when VT-x is enabled

Tags: usb, windows-8.1, motherboard, virtualization, vt-x

The problem I have is that when I enable Intel Virtualization Technology (or VT-x) in my BIOS, it makes my USB 2.0 ports not work.
The USB 3 ports, on the other hand, are working.

This is happening **under Windows (W8.1 x64) but also under bios**, like if I don't connect a keyboard on my front USB 3 (or any USB3, I use front for convenience) I can't even get inside the BIOS. The first BIOS screen says "Keyboard not found" or something like that.

As soon as I disable VT-x, all USB ports are back to working again.

For information, I have an i7 2600 on an Asus P8Z68 V Pro Gen 3, and both Hibernate and Fast Boot are disabled on my Windows (although, I doubt it's a Windows problem since it happens in BIOS too, but not too sure about that, hence my asking here).

Thank you.

EDIT :
I've looked for the following :

- VT-x USB
- Intel virtualization USB
- enabling virtualization blocks usb 2
- only usb 3 wortking with virtualization enabled
- p8z68 virtualization usb

I found zero resources about this happening under BIOS.

Comment: What information have you found in researching the problem?  Having others find information you've already found and rejected is a waste for all parties involved.

Comment: Only thing I was able to find is someone who had the problem, but only under Windows, and fixed it by turning off Fast Boot : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigmcmurtry/archive/2013/08/25/enable-intel-virtualization-technology-under-windows-8-and-still-have-a-working-usb-keyboard.aspx

Comment: While researching, what keyword groups have you used?  Sometimes the difference between a successful search and a fruitless search is the use of the right keywords.  I'm just spitballing since I don't know what the problem is, and thus I've no idea what the solution might be.  If you can edit the question and add these details, I can recant my -1 vote.

Comment: I edited it. This seems to me to be a really weird problem and I don't have much hope, but the community here is quite skilled, so it's worth a try!

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I was able to solve a similar issue on my computer by disabling "Fast Boot" as you suggested in the comments.

I was having an issue where the displayport stopped working after I enabled "Intel Virtualization Technology" in my BIOS. Not sure why this solved my issue, but it's worth noting for anyone else that may be having this issue!